# Deal with Random Forest Overfitting

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

I am trying to deal with overfitting problems in Random Forest. Parameters I tried to reduce overfitting are max_depth, min_samples_leaf, min_samples_split. The train set has 2000 samples and the validation set has 500. I have tried to set the min_samples_leaf and the min_samples_split to be 10 to 50, and even set max_depth equal to 1. The problem is still there. For parameters like max_features and n_estimators, I think they are adequate and don't have large influence on the overfitting. What else can I do to reduce the overfitting in this case? (Btw, the AUC score on training set is 0.73 and on validation set is 0.53 so I assume this is overfitting)

I sincerely appreciate any help!

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. And read [mcve]. You will get more answers.

Comment: Thanks for comments. The train set has 2000 samples and the validation set has 500. I have tried to set the min_samples_leaf and the min_samples_split to be 10 to 50, and even set max_depth equal to 1. The problem is still there.

Comment: I'm sorry.  Please add this comment information into the question.  If there is code involved, then please include a *small* example that shows your problem.  This is way too broad and open-ended for most developers to understand or care about answering.  Did you read [mcve]?

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I am new to this. I already edit the question and there is no code involved. But thanks for the article, I have already read it!

Comment: Ok, this is binary classification (looks like it)? Are the train and validation sets from the same dataset, and the validation set is extracted using shuffle, or similar? What are `max_features` and `n_estimators`? Personally, I prefer to tune one of either `max_depth` or `min_samples_leaf` and leave the other.

Comment: The max_features is default setting(sqrt()) and n_estimators is 300. It is a binary classification and the train set and validation set are from same distribution and are random split. I tried to tune max_depth and min_samples_leaf which decrease the AUC on train set and increase the AUC on dev set a little bit but not enough.